# Pop up about security problems

Tags: security, browser, certificates, popup

[image: Screenshot]

I had a lot of these pop ups and I don't know if it's for real or not.

Comment: Correct your date and time. Try if this solves your issue.

Comment: Based on the screenshot, what made you to conclude that the pop-up is related to virus or some other malware? Consider following the advice noted by @Manubhargav. You can also tap on View Certificate and show us the output of it. Anyhow, which website is it?

Comment: That note popped up and when I clicked it, it lead to a site that scanned my phone and said I had malware, that's why I posted it cause I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: First make sure your date is correct. Are you sure your date is correctly set and still getting this warning?

Comment: BTW: As @Firelord already indicated, the popup nowhere talks about a virus. I've corrected the title of your question accordingly.

Comment: It is worth saying that, based on what you've said, it sounds like some form of adware for an app.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:** Correct your date, or Set the clock to update automatically

**Reason:** This security warning pops-up when the verification of certificate needs to be done but the requesting system is set to wrong date(usually to the past).
The security certificate is seen as **From Future**.
This is all related to certificate validation by the browser.
Related Stack Exchange [post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24704/system-time-and-certificates)

**NB:** This does not harm your phone (and certainly it's not a virus)

**EDIT:** There can be other reasons as suggested by @Lie Ryan - due to certificate mismatch / weak encryption / browser not trusting the [CA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority)

Comment: There are other possible reasons why you may get invalid TLS/SSL certificate warning other than expired certificate (or certificate issued to future date). The certificate may be issued for a different domain name than the server you're trying to connect to, or it may use a weak cryptography that are no longer trusted by the system, or it may be issued by a certificate authority that the browser doesn't trust. In any case, you may want to view the certificate and find out what's wrong with it. Or bail out to safety.

Comment: I didn't understand the reasoning for revision 4 and revision 5. Would you please care to explain a little?

Comment: @Firelord   I thought it was not necessary to mention about virus since the original question was edited [removing the term virus](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/122825/revisions) for revision 4.  But then I thought it will help readers further to understand that android does not suffer from virus problems as many [posts about virus](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=virus) have come up in the recent past, hence revision 5.